# "FAILED TO DECODE IMAGE" Flutter Base64 Image Decode not working Properly some base64, though that base64 is converting on online tools

Tags: flutter, image, base64, byte, file-conversion

I am using flutter and decoding the image from base64 while decoding the image flutter shows me the images of almost every images but it is not showing me the images of some base64. What could be the possible solution.

I have used

```
      signatureImage = Image.memory(base64Decode(base64data));
```

Image.memory() I have used. I want to know more methods where I can set base64 to Image

Comment: what are the first 8 bytes of `base64Decode(base64data)` in **hexadecimal**?

Comment: ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 01 2c 01 2c 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 10

Comment: The Question is, why you need to decode the image ? what you want to achieve ?

Comment: looks like a correct `jpg` image signature, what if you add `errorBuilder:` in `Image.memory` - is it called? if so, with what `error`?

Comment: I handle the situation from backend . I have compress the base64 in java and then i send the base 64 to frontend